# How to write XCUITests on CallKit in iOS?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, callkit, xcuitest

Is it feasible to automate Call Kit in iOS devices? Our expectation is to launch 2 instances in parallel and need to check - **"Triggering a call from one device and responding to the call in another device"**.

Currently, we are using VoIP pushes for getting the Calls in our iOS devices using Call Kit.

if yes, Can you please share some references?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770405/can-we-automate-audio-video-calls-in-native-ios-devices